# Polynomials and Countability

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, polynomials

Lemma 1):

The set of polynomials of degree n with integers coefficients (P) is countable.

Proof: There exists a bijection between P and $\mathbb{Z}^{n+1}$. Hence P is countable.

Corollary:

The set of real numbers that are roots of some polynomial of degree n with integer coefficients is countable.

Proof:For each fixed polynomial in $P$ , it has at most n distinct roots. Hence the set is countable.

May someone please elaborate on the proof in the corollary? What bijection could we set up?

Comment: Since the polynomials are countable, you can enumerate them: $f_1, f_2, f_3, \dots$. If $f_1$ has $n$ roots, call them $r_1,\dots,r_n$. If $f_2$ has $m$ roots, call them $r_{n+1},\dots,r_{n+m}$, etc...

Comment: $P(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + \cdots + a_n z^n$ maps to the tupple $(a_0,a_1,\cdots, a_n)$ which is in $\mathbb Z^{n+1}$

Comment: Note that what you get here isn't _directly_ a bijection, because a root may belong to many different polynomials (in fact, countably infinitely many!) — what you're showing is that there's an injection from $\mathbb{N}$ into the set of algebraic numbers (by way of enumerating the roots of each polynomial in turn), and certainly there's an injection from the set of algebraic numbers into $\mathbb{N}$ (e.g., take the floor to map to $\mathbb{Z}$ and then use your favorite bijection), so there must be a bijection.

Comment: @Nick so essentially  the roots are countable by the diagonal argument, right?

Answer (score 1):

For each polynomial $P$ with integer coefficients, let $Z_P$ be the set of its zeros. Then $Z_P$ is finite. The set that you wish to prove that it is countable is the set $\bigcup_{P\in\mathbb Z[z]}Z_P$. It is a countable union of finite sets. Therefore it is finite or countable. But it cannot be finite, since it contains $\mathbb Q$. So…

Comment: Its not immediately clear to me that it contains $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: $p/q$ is a root of the polynomial $qx-p=0$

Comment: @MatthewDaly for each polynomial, there must exist atleast one solution, right?

Comment: @topologicalmagician No. For instance, $x^2+1$ has zero real roots.